# Android - TextView does not appear at all

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I want each TextView appear under each ImageButton but the TextView in my case does not appear at all and I don't understand why. Thank you for helping.
This is my activity.xml :

> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
>     android:layout_width="200dp"
>     android:layout_height="200dp"
>     android:layout_gravity="center"
>     android:src="@drawable/logo" />
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="horizontal" >
>
>     <ImageButton
>         android:id="@+id/imageButtonProjet"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
>         android:adjustViewBounds="false"
>         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
>         android:src="@drawable/projet" />
>
>     <ImageButton
>         android:id="@+id/imageButtonWorkitem"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
>         android:adjustViewBounds="false"
>         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
>         android:src="@drawable/workitem" />
>
>     <ImageButton
>         android:id="@+id/imageButtonUser"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
>         android:adjustViewBounds="false"
>         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
>         android:src="@drawable/user" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@id/imageButtonProjet"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
>         android:text="Projects"
>         android:textColor="@color/text_color" >
>     </TextView>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@id/imageButtonWorkitem"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
>         android:text="WorkItem"
>         android:textColor="@color/text_color" >
>     </TextView>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@id/imageButtonUser"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
>         android:text="Users"
>         android:textColor="@color/text_color" >
>     </TextView>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

I would greatly appreciate your help.Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post a rough sketch of exactly what you want...are your images

Comment: just noting that you have 3 answers here and haven't accepted any of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layout_below works only for relative layouts.If you still want to do using LinearLayout then here is how.You are just using one LinearLayout that has a horizontal orientation. All this does it arrange the items horizontally and so the textviews go out of the screen. You need a 2 child LinearLayouts that has orientation set to horizontal and the parent with orientation vertical.

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

     <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
     <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >
     <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/imageButtonProjet"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
     android:adjustViewBounds="false"
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
     android:src="@drawable/projet" />

     <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/imageButtonWorkitem"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
     android:adjustViewBounds="false"
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
     android:src="@drawable/workitem" />

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/user" />
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:text="Projects"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
    android:text="WorkItem"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
    android:text="Users"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color" >
    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but the distance between ImageButton and TextView is quite large, can I reduce the distance between them?

Comment: change android:layout_marginBottom of image button to 0dp

Answer (score 1):

```
android:layout_below
```

Doesn't apply to `LinearLayout`. You should be using `RelativeLayout` to force items to appear in positions in relation to each other.

Depending on where you want your `ImageButton`s to appear, you might need to add something like

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageButtonWorkitem"
  android:layout_below="@id/imageButtonWorkitem"
```

or

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageButtonWorkitem"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageButtonWorkitem"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, when I use RelativeLayout they appears one on the other

Comment: The point I was making is that you're using concepts that don't belong with each other. Either use RelativeLayout and layout_below and so on or use LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alternate between your imageviews within the linear layout. Also, you might not be seeing the textviews at all because the overall layout might be too tall.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonProjet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/projet" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageButtonProjet"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:text="Projects"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color" >
</TextView>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonWorkitem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/workitem" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageButtonWorkitem"
    android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
    android:text="WorkItem"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color" >
</TextView>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/user" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageButtonUser"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
    android:text="Users"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If his ImageViews his too tall to fit in a screen.. then the best solution would be to use ScrollViews which will fit in all those circumstances ../

Comment: Yes, a scrollview surrounding the whole thing would be appropriate if what I said was the case. I can't tell from his layout and his device if the textviews were not displaying simply due to height.